# Legend in ggplot2, remove level

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

My data:

```
df <- data.frame(sp = c(LETTERS[1:8]),
                 tr = c("NS", "LS", "NS", "LS", "LS", "HS", "HS", "HS"),
                 bv = c(14, 5, 11, 5.6, 21, 5.4, 2, 4.8),
                 av = c(0.0, 14, 21, 48.4, 15, 55.6, 37, 66.2))
```

I do the bar plot

```
library(reshape2)
df1 <- melt(df, id.vars = c("sp", "tr"))

ggplot(aes(sp, value, fill = variable) , data = df1) + theme_classic() + 
  geom_bar(aes(lty = tr), lwd = 1.2, data = df1, stat = "identity", colour = "black", width =.8) + 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom" ) +
  scale_linetype_discrete(name = "ja")
```

Output
[image]
  What I does not like is the legend. I'd like to have just the lines type from the second part "`ja`" and remove "`variable`" part. I'd like to have the white background in the legend boxes, not the grey one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove the `variable` legend by setting `fill = FALSE` in `guides` and you change the backgroundcolor with `override.aes` in `guide_legend` (also inside `guides`) as follows:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(sp, value, fill = variable)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(lty = tr), lwd = 1.2, stat = "identity", colour = "black", width =.8) + 
  scale_linetype_discrete(name = "ja") +
  guides(fill = FALSE,
         lty = guide_legend(override.aes = list(lty = c('dotted', 'dashed', 'solid'),
                                                fill = "white"))) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

this results in the following plot:

[image]