# Removing elements from the legend in ggplot when plotting facets with multiple aes settings

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, facet, legend-properties

I'm using the code below to generate a simple chart:

```
# Data and libs
data(mtcars)
reuire(ggplot2); require(ggthemes)

# Chart def
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, colour = as.factor(vs))) +
    geom_point(aes(colour = factor(cyl))) + 
    facet_wrap(~ cyl) +
    guides(colour = guide_legend(title = "Something")) +
    geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
    theme_pander()
```

[image: Plot]

How can I remove the lines from the legend? I'm interested in legend showing only dots with corresponding colours without the lines derive from the `geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE)`.

---

I had a look at the question on [*Turning off some legends in a ggplot*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604435/turning-off-some-legends-in-a-ggplot), however, after reading it it wasn't clear to me how to disable the legend elements pertaining to a specific `geom`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Turning off some legends in a ggplot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14604435/turning-off-some-legends-in-a-ggplot)

Comment: add `show_guide = FALSE` to `geom_smooth`

Comment: @scoa `show_guide` is deprecated, but he could use `show.legend = FALSE` instead. That's actually simpler than my answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Legend in ggplot2, remove level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32780092/legend-in-ggplot2-remove-level)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to override the `aes`:

```
guides(colour = guide_legend(title = "Something", override.aes = list(linetype = 0)))
```

```r
# Data and libs
library(ggplot2)
library(ggthemes)

# Chart def
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, colour = as.factor(vs))) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = factor(cyl))) + 
  facet_wrap(~cyl) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) + 
  guides(colour = guide_legend(title = "Something", override.aes = list(linetype = 0))) +
  theme_pander()
```

[image]

For some reason, `theme_pander` looks different for me though.

**Update**:
Alternatively, you could use `show.legend = FALSE`, as scoa pointed out, which I'd actually prefer:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, colour = as.factor(vs))) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = factor(cyl))) + 
  facet_wrap(~cyl) +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, show.legend = FALSE) + 
  guides(colour = guide_legend(title = "Something")) +
  theme_pander()
```